# Memory Allocation Error in C

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, realloc, gmp

I am trying to get the binary representation of a big integer in GMP. I am storing 1's and 0's in an array called **expBinary**. I use malloc to allocate a memory of size of "int", then use **realloc** to increase this memory whenever a new bit is added. The conversion is running perfectly without any issues, but when I try to allocate any more memory using malloc after the while loop, it is giving me **segmentation fault** when I call the same code a **second time**, first time it gives me no segmentation fault. I have checked and the "expBinary" is not storing anything out of bounds, I have given the code below

```
int binarySize = 0;                                                        
int * expBinary = malloc(sizeof(int));                                 
int i = 0;                                                                  

// Run until exp == 0                                                       
while(mpz_cmp_ui(exp,0) != 0)                                               
{                                                                           
    binarySize++;                                                           
    expBinary = (int*) realloc(expBinary,(binarySize));                     
    // Getting LSB of exp                                                   
    if(mpz_even_p(exp) != 0)                                                
        expBinary[i] = 0;                                                   
    else                                                                    
        expBinary[i] = 1;                                                                                                                                 
    // Incrmenting variables                                                
    i++;                                                                    
    // Dividing exponent by 2                                               
    mpz_tdiv_q_ui(exp,exp,2);                                               
}                                                                           

// This line is giving error
int * temp = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Is this on linux? use [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org)

Comment: [Please don't cast the result of `realloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Comment: Its in Mac (Unix) but I guess it will work the same in Linux. I removed the cast but its still showing the same error.

Comment: Yes valgrind does work on Mac.

Comment: @iharob without macports? *please do tell or link*. And may you live to a hundred healthy years if this pans out =)

Comment: @WhozCraig I have no idea, I just know that it works on mac, read it somewhere.

Comment: @AkshayGupta I see you are a new user did you take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)?

Comment: @iharobit is among the top-three utils that I've craved for my Mac for a few years. Time to stoke the search engines and see if the gnomes have been busy. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using an `int` array, then this is wrong

```
expBinary = (int*) realloc(expBinary,(binarySize));
```

it should be

```
expBinary = realloc(expBinary, binarySize * sizeof(*expBinary));
```

or equivalently,

```
expBinary = realloc(expBinary, binarySize * sizeof(int));
```

I prefer `sizeof(*expBinary)` for obvious reasons, and also, if `realloc()` fails  you loose reference to the previous pointer so I recommend this

```
void *tmp;
tmp = realloc(expBinary, binarySize * sizeof(int));
if (tmp == NULL)
    handleFailureHereAndDontContinueToTheNextLineAndFree_expBinary_Please();
expBinary = tmp;
```

Now, if you want to print the representation using any `printf("%s\n", expBinary);` you should use `char *` instead, in that case you should consider that `sizeof(char) == 1` always, and you will need one extra byte at the end of the `1`'s and `0`'s with the value `'\0'`.